# WebClient keeps crashing my thread without throwing an exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, crash, webclient, downloadstring

I'm using a `WebClient` to download a html file:

```
        private static string PullHTML(string url)
        {
            string data = null;
            if (url != null)
            {
                if (!WebCache.TryGetValue(url, out data))
                {
               //THIS CODE IS REACHED
                    try
                    {
                        using (QuickWebClient wc = new QuickWebClient())
                        {

                            data = wc.DownloadString(url); //Debugging ends here
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebException e)
                    {
               //THIS CODE IS NEVER REACHED
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        data = e.Message;
                    }
               //NEITHER IS THIS
                    WebCache.Add(url, data);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
```

---

```
        private class QuickWebClient : WebClient
        {
            protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
            {
                WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
                w.Timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
                return w;
            }
        }
```

This is run in a separate thread (I overloaded it for debugging purposes, the problem started before). Now, this code will often seemingly crash the thread it's running in. The thread basically stops. I can't debug it, because the debugger will leave as soon as it reaches the `DownloadString` line. It will just act as if I pressed *F5*. No exception is thrown. The thread does not continue. What's happening?

Comment: Turn on Break on All Exceptions.

Comment: I went through the code step by step. It cancelled the debugging by itself.

Comment: 'It cancelled the debugging by itself' usually means it got stuck on a blocking call.

Comment: Are you going to even attempt the `try` and `catch` with `if (!WebCache.TryGetValue(url, out data))`?  Are you even entering the `if`?

Comment: Yes, I'm entering the if.

Comment: You're definitely not calling a function that contains a `return` incorrectly?